# Automatically cut text on length over limiter?

Tags: yii2, redactor

I'm using redactor limiter plugin, but I have a problem when I copy paste to text editor, it can paste the text even text is over than number I limit, Can I cut text automatically to max length I just defined on paste?

If so, please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use traditional `onchange` javascript